# Isn't my GitHub SSH key supposed to free me from writing credentials every time?

Tags: git, authentication, ssh, credentials

A colleague has told me to make a ssh key and import it in GitHub. Before I did that, I was getting "access denied" errors (or similar) when `npm` checked out dependencies from GitHub, but now it works fine. However, I still need to enter my credentials every time I push to the remote. Isn't the SSH key supposed to free me from that?

(Note: The passphrase of my ssh key is empty)

**Edit:** I just the [GitHub docs on this](https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/) and it seems that the problem is that I've checked out via HTTPS instead of SSH. Is that so?

Comment: Use `git remote -v` to show your remotes. If they start with "HTTPS", then it isn't using SSH.  Use `git remote set-url` to change it to the SSH location.

Comment: @vcsjones: I just did that and it worked. Please post it as an answer so I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git remote -v` to show your remotes. If they start with "HTTPS", then it isn't using SSH. Use `git remote set-url` to change it to the SSH location.